# Cannot run JHipster docker

Tags: docker, centos, kubernetes, jhipster, openshift-origin

Im trying to run https://hub.docker.com/r/jhipster/jhipster/ as part of a Jenkins build on OpenShift, with CentOS host, but am getting the following error:

```
Failed to start container with docker id 38194274e387 with error: 

Error response from daemon: 
{"message":"invalid header field value \"oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: 
starting container process caused \\\"chdir to cwd (\\\\\\\"/home/jenkins/workspace/copy-of-sw\\\\\\\") set in config.json failed: no such file or directory\\\"\\n\""}
```

The dockerfile contents can be viewed on https://hub.docker.com/r/jhipster/jhipster/~/dockerfile/

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Post the last lines of the Dockerfile, something is wrong in the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` directive, in fact post the whole Dockerfile, as  directory does not exist

Comment: Ive added a link to the dockerfile.

Comment: this looks like a jenkins specific error...it doesn't find some file...this means the docker container might be misconfigured in your use case

Answer (score 1):

For a Jenkins build, you want to use the CI image `jhipster/jhipster-ci-stack` https://hub.docker.com/r/jhipster/jhipster-ci-stack/

That Docker image `jhipster/jhipster` is used for developing with the generator, it will not work correctly in a Jenkins pipeline unless you are changing the generator and want to test that.  How to use that image can be found in the "Docker installation (for advanced users only)" of https://jhipster.github.io/installation/

Comment: Thanks @Jon Ruddell, this is good to know. However, even with jhipster/jhipster-ci-stack I still get errors.

Comment: Does `/home/jenkins/workspace/copy-of-sw` exist in your docker image?  It does not by default.  It looks like you have an issue similar to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26855 (the directory didn't exist, solved by setting a `WORKDIR`) but we'll need more information in your question on your process to figure out exactly what's wrong.